# Different ways to assign a group.

Tags: combinatorics

A class is going on a field trip, there are 6 vans and each van can hold 5 students and 1 teacher. There are 25 students and 5 teachers going, How many different ways can you assign groups.

My approach to this question was as follows.

$$6 \cdot C(25,5) \cdot C(5,1) = 1593900$$

However, when reviewing with another peer they mentioned that permutations should be used because order matters, there needs to be 1 teacher per 5 students.

This confuses me. If that were the case, why the need for the 6th vans as 5 teachers will be placed in 5 vans with a maximum of 5 students making it only 5 vans.

Because the problem states that there is a 6th van I would assume being used would not the above solution be the answer?

thanks.

Comment: each van can hold any combination of 5 students out of 25 and any combination of 1 teacher out of 5.   So 6 vans * C(25,5) * C(5,1)

Comment: Then would it be more appropriate to sum the combinations for student and teacher? with the assumption that each van could have 0-5 students and 0-1 teacher, then multiply the results by 6

Comment: I guess that is the source of the confusion since the problem does not state it clearly.

Comment: I appreciate your willingness to work with me through this. Thanks